# Changing '\\' to '/' on path string

Tags: haskell

Im trying to read and write files from a given path. The problem is that when I copy the path from a file (Im on Windows) it uses '\' as a path separator but haskell doesn´t seem to understand it because for example: "aDir\file.txt" mistakenly reads '\f' which is an invalid character.

That´s why I tryed to create a function which "normalizes" (transforms) this paths into one with '/' as path separator (which works fine), but it doesn´t work, I asume, because of the same reason.
Is it there any built in function that already does this for me?

```
main :: String -> (String -> String) -> IO ()
main path transformation = do
    let normalizedPath = normalizePath path
    contenido <- readFile normalizedPath
    let resultado = transformation contenido
    writeFile normalizedPath resultado

normalizePath :: String -> String
normalizePath = map f 
    where
        f '\\' = '/'
```

Comment: I think you should not do this at all in the first place. Instead, when you "copy" the path from your file into your source, just escape the backslashes by adding an extra backslash in front of them. For example, instead of putting `fileName = "aDir\file.txt"` in your Haskell file, put `fileName = "aDir\\file.txt"`.

Comment: The thing is that what Im realy trying to avoid is exactly that. So that when I do a more complicated program that takes a path it could do it automaticaly.

Comment: When you write a more complicated program, you will have the program read directly from the file, and it will not be subject to this escaping restriction. In other words, if you had a configuration file with the text `aDir\file.txt` in it, and used `readFile` to read that file into a `String`, the `String` it would produce would *already* be the same as the `String` produced by the literal `"aDir\\file.txt"`.

Comment: You don't have define `normalizePath`; use `System.FilePath.normalise` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you make it more complicated than it is. You can just use a `map` here:

```
normalizePath :: String -> String
normalizePath = map f
    where f '\\' = '/'
          f x = x
```

We here thus convert all `'\\'` characters to `'/'` characters.

Note that the string `"aDir\file.txt"` does *not* contain a backslash, since it is parsed with a `'\f'`, which is a form feed character. If the string contains a backslash, as a string literal it is formatted as `"aDir\\file.txt"`.

For example:

```
Prelude> normalizePath "aDir\\file.txt"
"aDir/file.txt"
```

You can enter *raw* strings through the [**`raw-strings-qq`** package [Hackage]](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/raw-strings-qq-1.1/). For example:

```
$ ghci -XQuasiQuotes 
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :{
Prelude| normalizePath :: String -> String
Prelude| normalizePath = map f
Prelude|     where f '\\' = '/'
Prelude|           f x = x
Prelude| :}
Prelude> import Text.RawString.QQ
Prelude Text.RawString.QQ> normalizePath [r|C:\Users\admin\Desktop\file.txt|]
"C:/Users/admin/Desktop/file.txt"
```

Comment: Oh, you´re right. But still when I do:
normalizePath "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\file.txt" it throws:

lexical error in string/character literal at character 'U'

Comment: @CimimUxMaio: the reason is that `"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\file.txt"` is *not* a valid string *literal*, the `\U` is incorrect. If you want to use a backslash in your string, you need to escape it, like `"C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\file.txt"`

Comment: So there isn´t any way of programming it so that I get automaticaly "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\file.txt" ?

Comment: @CimimUxMaio: you can enter "*raw*" strings through template haskell yes, but that will behind the curtains just escape the backslash, see edit.